# How to print all array values in php by bash command?

Tags: php, arrays, bash, exec, shell-exec

i have an array in my PHP script,

```
$args=array("red","green","blue","yellow");
```

i want to execute a bash command who prints all values of an array.

```
red
green
blue
yellow
```

i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447853/passing-array-argument-to-bash-from-php) question and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447853/passing-array-argument-to-bash-from-php), i don't want just to pass an array as an argument, i want to print each value of my array, i tried this

```
exec('echo ' . '"${args[@]}"');
```

but i got

```
sh: 1: Bad substitution
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in `bash`?

Comment: i want to pass each value of this array as a parametre in bash, i use echo like an example

Comment: php array declaration can be pretty complex and multiline

Comment: @anubhava you mean i can't do that?

Comment: @GerardRoche no i read that question, i don't want just to pass array argument to bash, i want to print EACH value of my array

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean. Revise the question.

Comment: @GerardRoche Ok, i updated my question

Comment: What bash command? echo? Do you expect the following to work? `exec('echo hello');`, does it work? If yes, then doesn't the following work: `exec('echo ' . implode (' ', ['a', 'b', 'c']));`